# Call parent class function

Tags: python, nested, super

It is first time I try to use `super()`, I tried many little changes to this code, but with all I got error on line where `super()` is.

I saw similar questions on SO, but they are not working in my case or I do something wrong

Could you help me to call `getMessagesBodies()` from `list()` ?

```
class Gmail:
    def getMessagesBodies(self, text):
        return self.unpackPayload(text)

    def unpackPayload(self, text):
        return (text)


    class getMessages:

        def __init__(self):
            self.service = auth()

        def list(self,text):
            return super(self).getMessagesBodies(text)  # error here, how to call getMessagesBodies properly?
```

Comment: Assuming your indentation is fine in your actual code, getMessages does not inherit from anything

Comment: Just edited, now indentation is as I wanted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you never specified what the parent class was for the `getMessages` class.

You should define the class like so:

```
class getMessages(Gmail):
```

Unless your child class is overriding the `getMessagesBodies()` function, you actually do not have to use `super()` to specify that you want to call the parent function. By using `self.getMessagesBodies()` in your child class it will automatically call the parent's function since the child inherits all the same functions from the parent.

So you can call the function without using super like:

```
self.getMessagesBodies(text)
```

Also, just a tip is that `getMessages` seems more like a function name then a class. Usually classes are fully capitalized and are an object, not an action.